# Multivariable Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Use the chain rule to determine the derivative of g(x,y):= xy along the path f(t):= \begin{pmatrix} cos(t)\\ sin(t) \end{pmatrix}.

How to do such questions?

Answer (score 0):

The chain rule is as follows 
$$\frac{dg(x,y)}{dt} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Since you want to determine the derivative of $g(x,y)$ with respect to $t$ along $f$ we get that $\frac{dx}{dt} = -\sin(t)$ and $\frac{dy}{dt} = \cos(t)$

therefore $$\frac{dg(x,y)}{dt} = -y\sin(t) + x\cos(t)$$

Comment: What about @Abelois solution?

Comment: @ZDD It's the same as this one...

Answer (score 0):

By the chain rule,
\begin{equation}
(g\circ f)'(t) = \frac{dg}{d(x,y)}(f(t))\;·\;\frac{df}{dt}(t) = \left.\left(y\quad x\right)\right|_{(\cos(t),\sin(t))}\;·\;\left(-\sin(t)\quad \cos(t)\right)^T =\\ =\left(\sin(t)\quad \cos(t)\right)\;·\;\left(-\sin(t)\quad \cos(t)\right)^T = -\sin^2(t) + \cos^2(t) ,
\end{equation}
where dg/d(x,y) denotes the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

This is by the chain rule, but you can also do it replacing first:
\begin{equation}
(g\circ f)(t) = \sin(t) \cos(t) \implies (g\circ f)'(t) = \cos(t)\cos(t) + \sin(t) [-\sin(t)] =\\
=\cos^2(t) - \sin^2(t).
\end{equation}

Comment: What about @Ziad solution?

Comment: @ZDD You realize that both solutions by Abelois and Ziad are the same...?

Comment: Yes, I saw it after giving my answer. Notice that his "formula" for the chain rule is obtained by the Jacobian matrix that I wrote. Also, @Ziad must finally replace $f(t)$ in $(x,y)$.

Comment: Just noticed. Thank You!